# AngularJS Directive or Service?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-service, angularjs-controller

My current understanding of AngularJS tells me that **Directives** should only contain *DOM Manipulation* and **Services** everything which has to do with *logic and data handling*.

In my case I'm unsure which to use. I got an Object which contains three functions:

```
// Creates a documentFragment & normal element.
// Returns the fragment.
createElem: function(htmlStr) {
    var frag = document.createDocumentFragment(),
    temp = document.createElement("div");

    temp.innerHTML = htmlStr;

    while (temp.firstChild) {
        frag.appendChild(temp.firstChild);
    }

    return frag;
},
// Removes all created childNodes.
deleteElem: function(htmlStr) {
    while (htmlStr.firstChild) {
        htmlStr.removeChild(htmlStr.firstChild);
    }
},
// Redirects to page.
openGate: function(keyStr) {
    var open = function() {
        $location.path("/" + keyStr).replace();
        $rootScope.$apply();
    };

    setTimeout(open, 500);
}
```

I want to have access to all of them through my AngularJS application.

But I'm not sure whether I should make this a Service or Directive.

**Reasons against Directive**

All of them (okay maybe two out of three) aren't *directly* manipulating or changing the DOM. Even that I create and delete Elements, there must applied somewhere else like `elem.insertBefore( createElem("<div></div>") );` in a Controller. The `openGate();` function simply changes the location and has absolutely nothing to do with the DOM.

**Reasons against Service**

I'm not really handling any data. In `createElem();` I create a `documentFragment` which is a Node without a parent. So if I call the function, nothing will happen inside of my DOM until I insert it somewhere.

---

Maybe I should split them up into *Directives* and *Services*? Otherwise they will always stay in the same context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're correct in splitting functions up into Directives and Services.

Services are not just for logic handling. The main purpose of services are to contain information that is intended to be shared amongst other parts of your site, such as controllers and directives. So you can think about it this way:

Am I going to be manipulating the DOM ? Use a directive.

Am I going to be sharing this information amongst various components of my site? Use a Service (i.e service, factory, or provider).

Comment: Thanks, that cleared my mind. But what about `openGate();`? It's not sharing information through the application nor is it manipulating the DOM.

Comment: If it's not a function that you want to use in multiple places, feel free to put it in a controller.

Comment: If that answered it for you, can you mark the answer correct please! Thanks!